# Add opacity to jssor slider nearby visible images

Tags: slider, opacity, jssor

I want to add opacity to the nearby images of a jssor slider.

I found this old one but I cannot get it to work:

[jssor nearby slider opacity upcoming photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326565/jssor-nearby-slider-opacity-upcoming-photos)

especially this part:

```
<div data-u="slides" id="slideimage-content">
    <?php foreach ($sectionImage as $key => $value) {?>
        <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;border-style:none; ">
            <img data-u="image" src="<?php echo $value['url'] ?>" style="border-style:none;"/>
            <div class="slidecover slidecover<?php echo $key ?> coverdark"></div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>


</div>
```

Jfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/sLjfu7xc/3/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For now, you can add static cover above to make it appear like that.
Download jssor slider dev pack, find the demo ‘examples/overlay-cover.html’.

Btw, we will implement this as built feature later.